# glm() vs. glmer() on repeated measures

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

Say I am curious about whether the relationship between class rank (rank) and passing a final test (pass) is dependent upon days until summer vacation (days until summer). In my dataset, I have Mary, George, Harry, Holly, and Bob (student), and I have information as to what classes they are in (class), and the years they took the test (year). How would I model this?

```
library(lme4)

year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003,
          2001, 2002,
          2003,
          1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004,
          1998, 1999, 2000)

class <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
           "B", "B",
           "B",
           "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",
           "E", "E", "E")

student <- c("Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary",
             "George", "George",
             "Harry",
             "Holly", "Holly", "Holly", "Holly", "Holly", "Holly",
             "Bob", "Bob", "Bob")

days_until_summer <- c(10, 12, 13, 20,
                           9, 10,
                       10,
                           3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 6,
                           15, 6, 11)

rank <- c(5, 5, 5, 5,
          8, 9,
          10,
          4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6,
          1, 1, 3)

pass <- c(0, 1, 0, 1,
          1, 1,
          0,
          0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
          1, 1, 0)

df <- data.frame(year, class, student, days_until_summer, rank, pass)
```

I am thinking of the following options:

GLM

```
glm_reg <- glm(pass ~ rank*days_until_summer + factor(year) + factor(class), df, family = "binomial")
```

Random effects model #1

```
hlm_reg1 <- glmer(pass ~ rank*days_until_summer + (1|year) + (1|class) + (1|student), df, family = "binomial")
```

Random effects model #2

```
hlm_reg2 <- glmer(pass ~ rank*days_until_summer + (1|year) + (1|class), df, family = "binomial")
```

Mixed effects model

```
hlm_reg3 <- glmer(pass ~ rank*days_until_summer + factor(year) + (1|class) + (1|justice_name), df, family = "binomial")
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated. I haven't been able to find a good primer on fixed effects vs. random effects for my specific purpose, but I'm curious as to what people think would be appropriate here. I've combed through some of the posts on here that works with similar datasets, but it seems like people suggest a variety of approaches, so I was wondering what would be best and what I should think about for a dataset of my specific structure.